# Reading cookie values returns empty value

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

I am trying to read cookie value but it is giving me an empty value. I can see the cookie key that I am trying to read in the application tab of chrome, but when I try to see that value using `document.cookie` in the console, the list of cookies does not include the key that I am trying to read. But when I look at the application tab, the key and value I am trying to access are there. Does anyone know why this case happens?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a cookie with `HttpOnly` set? As the name says, these cookies cannot be read by JavaScript code, they're only sent in http requests.

There's a column for that attribute in the cookie listing in the inspector.